# Многоугольник полилайнами в Inkscape

Tags: polyline, inkscape

Как нарисовать многоугольник полилайнами в Inkscape?

Ручками выглядит вот так(см. код)

```css
path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hex1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="fill" d="M50 0 0 40"></path>
    <path d="M0 40 0 90"></path>
    <path d="M0 90 50 130"></path>
    <path d="M50 130 100 90"></path>
    <path d="M100 90 100 40"></path>
    <path d="M100 40 50 0"></path>
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рисуем стандартный 6-угольник:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Смотрим в редакторе, шестиугольник нарисован одной линией:

Далее преобразуем в кривые (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

Выбираем инструмент редактора узлов (<kbd>F2</kbd>), выделяем все точки и жмем разбить контур в узлах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смотрим редактор, линия разорвана, но пока в одном теге. Жмем далее разбить контур  (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово. Линии все в отдельных тегах.